# Cell formula: Sum that changes range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet that adds the customer's individual orders up to create the total due. Suffice to say, the number of orders changes. So I was wondering if there was any way to have the cell add a specific range above it, so to speak. For example, the cell formula changes depending upon a number of orders (i have that number) and then adds the cells that number above it. For example, if the customer had 2 orders, the cell ( D45, for the exampl) would have the formula "=Sum(D43:D44)" but that formula would change when rg got to the next place where it needed to add a different order. I could just add them and equate the value in that cell to that, but I want to be able to change those numbers and that total dynamically. Thanks in advance.

Edit: as suggested, here's what I have so far code-wise
`iws.Cells(Parse - 1, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum( R[" & (OrdCt * 2) * -1 & "],C[0]: R[- 1 ],C[0])"`
I'm parsing through the spreadsheet, so I don't know exactly what cell I am in at a given time. I just know how many orders I have (which is stored in OrdCt) and each order has an extra tab for charges, so for each order I need to add 2 spaces. I'm expecting that the formula will be put into that specific cell and I can change the total of the orders before that and it will be reflected in that cell.

Comment: Please post some test data and expected outcome in the original post using edit.

Comment: Why is this [excel-vba] ? Seems like [excel-formula] would be a better fit. Do you actually have VBA code for this? If so, please include it and note the area you are having trouble with.

Comment: It would still be easier if you would post a mock up of the data and expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for the Range property called `.FormulaR1C1` which refers to row and column offsets. Ill refer you to this link [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/formulaR1C1.html). Since you're using VBA your code might look something like

```
Public Sub SumOrders(target As Range, numOrders As Integer)
    'Variables
    Dim rOffset As Integer
    rOffset = numOrders * -1

    'Set Formula
    target.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & rOffset & "]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])"  
End Sub
```

Perhaps this is convoluted, but try to extrapolate
Cheers!

Comment: Ok, so here's what I have for the formula `iws.Cells(Parse - 1, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum( R[" & (OrdCt * 2 + 1) * -1 & "],C[0]: R[- 2 ],C[0])" ` I know that looks pretty convoluted, but it sounds like my best bet. I keep getting the error "invalid use of property"

Comment: You have commas between your row and column offsets :)  
I also recommend you perform that calculation outside of the function or put the whole thing in an extra pair of parentheses  
Dont forget to mark your question's answer if its solved. ;)

Comment: Now I keep getting a "application defined or object defined" error. everything else seems to work correctly, but it hits a snag when it get's to that equation. Would it have something to do with using the specific cell?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Excuse my ignorance. I think i fixed the problem. I'll run it through and see if it works.